# Error converting datat type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using a case statements to return 1,2,3,4 or 6 for a given code. The code in the db is stored as `(varchar(8),null)` but for some reason SQL is doing this automatically behind the scenes or either I instructed it, but I am getting an error of Error Converting Data type varchar to numeric and I do not understand why.  SQL Server 2008. Here is what I have written:

```
DECLARE @CM TABLE (
ENCOUNTER_ID VARCHAR(200)
, [MRN CM] VARCHAR(200)
, NAME VARCHAR(500)
, [CC GRP ONE SCORE] VARCHAR(2)
--, [CC GRP TWO SCORE] VARCHAR(20)
--, [CC GRP THREE SCORE] VARCHAR(20)
--, [CC GRP FOUR SCORE] VARCHAR(20)
--, [CC GRP FIVE SCORE] VARCHAR(20)
--, [CC LACE SCORE] VARCHAR(20)
)
--#####################################################################

INSERT INTO @CM
SELECT
C.PT_NO
, C.MED_REC_NO
, C.PT_NAME
, C.PRIN_DX_CD_1
--, C.PRIN_DX_CD_2
--, C.PRIN_DX_CD_3
--, C.PRIN_DX_CD_4
--, C.PRIN_DX_CD_5
--, C.CC_LACE_SCORE

FROM (
    SELECT PT_NO
    , MED_REC_NO
    , PT_NAME
    , CASE
        WHEN PRIN_DX_CD IN (
        443.9, 440.20
        )
        THEN CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(2))
      END AS PRIN_DX_CD_1

    FROM SMSDSS.BMH_PLM_PTACCT_V
    )C
```

Comment: So PRIN_DX_CD is the column in question? have you tried doing a cast on PRIN_DX_CD column to a decimal before comparing it's value?

Comment: You are right PRIN_DX_CD is the column in question. I have not tried to cast it as a decimal beforehand. I will try that now. I am just a bit confused since the table I am inserting the value to is also set at varchar.

Comment: You simply add single quotes around the numbers in your IN clause?  It's trying to compare varchar to numeric.

Comment: Your case statement is trying to compare a varchar with values that are of the data type decimal/numeric/float - you can't find a string inside a number so the conversion fails.

Comment: @Goat_CO that done did it, I purely blame it on my wisdom tooth awaiting extraction. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a VARCHAR field, change your IN criteria for string comparison:

```
 WHEN PRIN_DX_CD IN (
    '443.9', '440.20'
    )
```

Comment: Good point, you can do it the other way!  I just did it on the column, on the assumption that a SELECT might end up in there with more than the predefined values.